# A limit question (JEE $2014$)

Tags: calculus, limits, mathematica

The following is a JEE (A national level entrance test) question:

**Find the largest value of the non-negative integer ( a ) for which:**

$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \left( \dfrac{-ax + \sin(x-1) + a} { x + \sin(x-1) -1 } \right)^{\dfrac{1-x}{1-\sqrt x} } = \dfrac 1 4 $$

On solving this, we get $ a = 0 $ or $ a = 2 $. So we take the answer as $ 2 $. But the official answer key says that the answer is $ 0 $. The reason given (not in the official key - they simple contain the answer. I saw the reason in an "unofficial" solution to the question paper) is that if $ a = 2 $, then the term $\displaystyle \dfrac{-ax + \sin(x-1) + a} { x + \sin(x-1) -1 } $ tends to a negative value ( $-0.5$ ). So $ a = 0$.

**BUT**:

By putting $a = 2$ in the limit, and inputting that to wolframalpha ([http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim(+(+(-2x+%2B+2+%2B+sin(x-1)+)+%2F+(+x+-+1+%2B+sin(+x+-+1)+)+)+%5E+(+(1-x)%2F(1-sqrt(x))+)+)+as+x+tends+to+1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28+%28+%28-2x+%2B+2+%2B+sin%28x-1%29+%29+%2F+%28+x+-+1+%2B+sin%28+x+-+1%29+%29+%29+%5E+%28+%281-x%29%2F%281-sqrt%28x%29%29+%29+%29+as+x+tends+to+1)), the answer turns out to be $0.25$. So, by putting $ a = 2$ also, we get the same value of the limit - $0.25$.

How to solve this dispute? Also, could you please check with Mathematica? Unfortunately, I don't have access to it!

(This is very important as the change in the answer key will affect the rankings in a dramatic way)

Comment: I was expecting the question to pop up here. :D

Comment: Haha :D...I had to ask it. The replies on Brilliant weren't good enough! And this is important.

Comment: Not so important to me anyways. :P

Comment: This solves all problems for future readers ;-) -http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~kdjoshi/jee2014.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $a = 2$, we have - writing $x = 1 + \delta$ - the expression

$$\left(\frac{\sin\delta - 2\delta}{\sin\delta + \delta}\right)^{\Large\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{1+\delta}-1}}.\tag{1}$$

For most $0 < \lvert\delta\rvert < 1$, the exponent is not a rational number.

So the question is: Does raising a negative real number to a non-rational power make sense or not?

If you have no qualms about using complex numbers (like Wolfram), the expression makes sense, and the limit as $\delta\to 0$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, no problem.

The makers of the test apparently had qualms about using complex numbers and decided that the expression $(1)$ doesn't make sense in general.

Comment: I don't think that in a level entrance test knowledge of complex exponentiation is assumed.

Comment: @egreg It actually isn't there in our syllabus. However, I was confused as to why wolframalpha said "OK" to $ a = 2 $. Makes sense now.

Comment: Sorry for digging a 7 year old post, but how do we know that the exponent is not a rational number. Indeed, I have no reason to believe that it is rational , but how to prove that it is an irrational number ?

Comment: @An_Elephant: the exponent takes both rational and irrational values as $\delta\to 0$ because the exponent is a continuous function of $\delta$ (remember intermediate value theorem for continuous functions).

Answer (score 8):

Let's study the base of the exponential:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{-ax+\sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1}\overset{\mathrm{H}}{=}
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-a+\cos(x-1)}{1+\cos(x-1)}=\frac{1-a}{2}
$$
(“H” denotes an application of l'Hôpital's theorem). Thus the limit is non negative only for $a\le1$. In particular, being the base continuous after extending it to $0$ with the limit, if $a>1$ there is a neighborhood of $1$ where your function is not defined (the basis of an exponential must be non negative).

The limit now poses no problem, because the exponent is $1+\sqrt{x}$ (for $x\ne0$), so your limit is
$$
\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right)^2
$$
which is equal to $1/4$ if and only if
$$
\left(\frac{1-a}{2}=\frac{1}{2}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\frac{1-a}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\quad\text{and}\quad a\le1
$$
that is, $a=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the (finite) limit inside the main parenthesis ($\frac{1-a}2$), the limit of the exponent is $2$ (it simplifies to $x+\sqrt x$), and the full expression is positive.

Solution: $a=2.$

UPDATE:

The power of a negative (when $a=2$) can be dealt with with complex logarithms:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\ln(-|f(x)|)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(g(x)(\ln |f(x)|+i\pi))=\lim_{x\rightarrow1} g(x)\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(\ln |f(x)|+i\pi)=2\ln\frac12+2i\pi.$$

Comment: Agreed with that. However, the problem is, the base term (the non-exponent term) is negative. And exponential functions are defined for positive bases.

Comment: $(-\frac12)^2=\frac14.$

Comment: @ParthThakkar I believe that in JEE syllabus, calculus is introduced for real valued functions only.

Answer (score 3):

The official answer is correct.

Indeed, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(x-1)-a(x-1)}{\sin(x-1)+(x-1)}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\cos(x-1)-a}{\cos(x-1)+1}=\frac{1-a}{2}$$
Thus, if $a=2$, the base is negative in a neighbourhood of $1$, and, unless you consider complex exponentiation, you can't raise a negative number to an irratioanl number.

Comment: That is the doubt I have! Should I consider complex exponentiation? Wolframalpha still gives $0.25$ by putting $ a = 2 $ in the limit.

Answer (score -1):

See this

[image]

After simplification of question it becomes $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{{{1}-{a}}}{{2}}\right)}^{{{t}{e}{n}{d}{s}\to{2}}}$

[image]

$\displaystyle^{\left({t}{e}{n}{d}{s}\to{2}\right)}$ because the power after simplification is $\displaystyle{1}+√{x}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{{{x}\to{1}}}$

Now number **tends to 2** can be 1.99999999999999 which can be written as 199999999999999/100000000000000 which is basically **Odd Integer/Even Integer** thus a possibility of undefined if a = 2

If a=0 then the question is (+ve)^<tends to 2>
Therefore defined!

Thus a=0!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The MathJax is a little faulty, but I see where this comes from! This is an excerpt from the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zstLeL0sfLI&t=940s if anyone was curious.